# Lost extras where starting Activity by click on Notification (PendingIntent)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have application that receives push notifications. These push notifications contain a payload. When receiving this notification I parse these payload and add it as `Bundle` to the `packageIntent`.

```
Intent packageIntent = context.getPackageManager().
        getLaunchIntentForPackage(Constants.PUSH_PACKAGE_NAME);
// putting bundle
packageIntent.putExtras(extras);
packageIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, packageIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

finally I add the `PendingIntent` as "content intent" to the `Notification`

```
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

But when I'm clicking on received `Notification` the opened `Activity` has a empty `Bundle` on its `getIntent().getExtras()`. Why is it lost?

Comment: Please post your manifest. Is your `Activity` already open when you click on the notification? Do you have any custom objects in the `Bundle` or is it all normal stuff like `int` and `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` in place of `PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`
And also check `android:allowBackup="true"` inside your application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Using a different `PendingIntent` flag will get you nothing. What does `allowBackup` have to do with this problem? And why did this get an upvote?